# How to capture black and white video using in iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recording video in Black and White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113639/recording-video-in-black-and-white)
>   [How to capture the black and white video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975758/how-to-capture-the-black-and-white-video)

I am developing iPhone application. In this application i need to capture the video that video format is black and white video. I trying to solve this last one week. I don't know how solve this. If anybudy know how to capture the black and white video, here post your commands. give some example link and code also, It's needful for development.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975758/how-to-capture-the-black-and-white-video possibly from the same user

Answer (score 0):

coreimage (ios 5 or higher) have many of the video/image filters that can be configured to attain dramatic effects including the one you are looking for (b&w). 
checkout the documentation for the same:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/index.html